# JavaFX some GUI components have 2 second lag

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, lag

I have recently started to notice that when clicking on some components like MenuItems in a MenuBar, or Choicebox that before they actually show up it takes about 2 seconds.

I would click on a choicebox and then wait 2 seconds before the choicebox items come up. This is also with components from third party libraries like ControlsFX.

The strange thing is that this is for ALL java applications that use JavaFX. Not just my application so a bug on my end is out of the question. I have tried uninstalling all java versions and installing a lower version to no avail.

---

My current java version is **1.8.0_45** (JDK) x64 on a Windows 8.1 Pro x64.

I am certain it is not my computer that is not performing well.

**EDIT**:
There is litterally *nothing* that I could find on this matter. I tried asking the Java Community on their website but my post got deleted for an unspecified reason.

**EDIT 2**:
After some research I have noticed that java puts error entries in the windows event logbook http://prntscr.com/6vnlww (sorry it's in dutch) and please look below in the comments for a ProcMon dump of everything that happened between me clicking on a choicebox in java and the choicebox opening up the item choices.

Comment: Any change if you disable all internet connections? (Just a wild guess.)

Comment: When I turn on airplane mode it still does this.

Comment: have you restart your computer ??

Comment: Yes. I have restarted my computer MANY times. This has been going on for a month or so. I also never do stuff like hibernate or something. Always clean shutdown.

Comment: Try sysinternals process monitor to figure out what's happening on your system.

Comment: Hello @Roland What should I be looking for? I notice there is alot of this http://prntscr.com/6vn20f and softthinks is the creator of AlienRespawn. A backup utility from AlienWare. At the time I took the screenshot it shouldn't have been doing any backups or anything so...

Comment: Take a look at the [1st screenshot](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896645.aspx). There's a lot of data. Look at what's happening between the time when you click on a combobox until something shows up.

Comment: When I open a choicebox I noticed, aside from loading a long list of files it also started http://prntscr.com/6vnf6g and this is some more data http://pastebin.com/Mf51crSJ

Comment: I made a full dump of everything that happened from the start I clicked on the choicebox until it showed up. https://mega.co.nz/#!0o5niaAb!XV4W93m74_WFoPumzojpJLyIteW9cj73CqJnzsDUANc

Comment: Well, that shows only the Java process. But then again, even this "\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\G Data\AVKProxy\ExploitProtection64.dll" is suspicious. I suggest you boot into clean OS without having anything started. But first try out if the same problem happens on another PC. The problem is obviously on your system.

Comment: Thanks, by process of elimination I have identified that it is indeed Exploit Protection from GData (anti virus) that makes it lag. I will inform the creators of GData of this issue and hopefully they will solve it. For now I have disabled this functionality of GData.